# WASM contract deployment fails on public networks

Tags: ink

When I try to deploy any WASM contract using polkadot.js.org/apps, It fails with Error: `system.ExtrinsicFailed(Other)`.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: We need much more information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload the contract artifacts (`.wasm` file & `metadata.json`) separately instead of uploading the `.contract` bundle. If this fails too, Make sure that you are sending sufficient gas amount and try building the artifacts in *release* mode to reduce the contract size. Command for the same is `cargo +nightly contract build --release`

For more details, You can checkout the following tutorial: [How to deploy ink! smart contract](https://github.com/realnimish/polkadot-amm/blob/main/tutorial.md#deploying-the-smart-contract)

Comment: Good to hear that you got it to work! Could you mark you answer as "accepted" (by clicking on the checkmark)?

Answer (score 4):

The `Other` error usually signals that the wasm code uploaded was rejected. There are various reasons for it but the most common is that it uses some function from the `pallet-contracts` that is not available in your node version. Another common error is that the contract code is just too big. That usually happens when the `--release` flag isn't supplied to `cargo contract`.

Bar any further information the most plausible explanation is that your node is out of date. In newer versions of the node `Other` is replaced by the more descriptive `CodeRejected` error.

You should:

- Update to the newest [`substrate-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node)
- Check your contract size whether it above the limit defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/56c28e858b2c3d7a6649988bdf3f48fd2eeb6fc5/frame/contracts/src/schedule.rs#L516)

Comment: Even the simplest flipper contract when build with release flag was not uploading with the contract bundle on public testnets

Comment: I am not sure which test net you are talking about. You need to be more specific. But I would suspect that they are using a old version of pallet-contracts while you are using a new version of ink!.